# How to make a div to scroll down with the page using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div on a landing page, and i want it to scrol down the page when i am scrolling.

i try this:

```
var sub =document.getElementById("minisite_send_button");

window.onscroll = function (event) {
sub.style.position=fixed;
sub.style.top=200px;
}
```

but i get this error :

SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
sub.style.top=200px;

Why am i getting this? And how can i solve this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `fixed` and `200px` should be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fixed` and `200px` is treated as a variables name. You have to put it in quotes.

Just try with:

```
sub.style.position = 'fixed';
sub.style.top = '200px';
```